# PHP Script quite CPU hungry. Ideas on an workaround

Tags: php, performance, zend-framework, curl, gearman

Because Server costs are the greatest spending, we want to get more out of everyone.
How can we achieve, that more scripts can run on this server?

***What the Scrips are doing:***
We run 80 PHP Scripts on one Server and feed them with Jobs through Gearman.
The Scripts are looking up Websites with `cURL`, extract the needed Informations with `Zend_Dom_Query` and store the Data in an DB.
Each Script get feeded with ca. 1000 URLs which they have to look up.
Script example is down below.

***What's the Server made of:***
`lshw`s outpu:

```
description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: vsyscall64 vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 8191GiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31230 @ 3.20GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
```

Nevertheless this is an V-Server it's the only V-Server running on that server. It has also not 8191GB Memory more like 16GB.

To show you how exhausted the server is, here's `top`s output:

```
top - 14:45:04 up 8 days,  3:10,  1 user,  load average: 72.96, 72.51, 71.82
Tasks: 100 total,  72 running,  28 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 87.5%us, 12.2%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.3%st
Mem:  8589934588k total,  4349016k used, 8585585572k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   282516k cached
```

Not to forget here's the scripts main structure:

```
    // Get the Infos on which to crawl on
    $asin = explode(',', $job->workload());
    try {
        $userproducts = new App_Dbservices_U...();
        $konkurrenz = new App_Dbservices_K...();
        $repricingstream = new App_Dbservices_R...();

        $err = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($asin) - 3; $i = $i + 50) {
            $mh = curl_multi_init();
            $handles = array();
            for ($j = $i; $j < $i + 50; $j++) {
                if ((count($asin) - 3) > $j) {
                    if (isset($asin[$j])) {
                            // create a new single curl handle
                            $ch = curl_init();

                            // setting several options like url, timeout, returntransfer
                            // simulate multithreading by calling the wait.php scipt and sleeping for $rand seconds
                            $url = // URL
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 80);

                            // add this handle to the multi handle
                            $erroro[$j] = curl_errno($ch);
                            $errmsg[$j] = curl_error($ch);
                            curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);

                            // put the handles in an array to loop this later on
                            $handles[] = $ch;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // execute the multi handle
            $running = null;
            do {
                curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
            } while ($running > 0);

            // get the content (if there is any)
            $output = '';
            for ($k = 0; $k < count($handles); $k++) {
                // get the content of the handle
                $output[$k] = curl_multi_getcontent($handles[$k]);
                $_asin[$k]['asin'] = $asin[$j - 50 + $k];
                $_asin[$k]['condition'] = $condition[$j - 50 + $k];
                $_asin[$k]['pId'] = $pId[$j - 50 + $k];

                if ($output[$k] != '')
                {
                    // get the dom of each page
                    $dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($output[$k]);

                    // get the sellerInfos of each page
                    $seller = $dom->query('div.Offer');

                    if (count($seller) > 0) {
                        // get the price out of the string
                        $seller_i = 0;
                        $selfCameOver = false;
                        foreach ($seller as $d2) {
                            if ($seller_i <= 6 OR $selfCameOver === false) {
                                $itemHtml = '';
                                foreach($d2->childNodes as $node) {
                                    $itemHtml .= $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($node);
                                }
                                $dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($itemHtml);

                                $itemPrice = $dom->query('span.Price');
                                foreach($itemPrice as $ItemPrice)
                        {
                            $_asin[$k]['price_end'][$seller_i] = 0.00;
                            $_asin[$k]['shipping_end'][$seller_i] = 0.00;
                            if (preg_match('/[0-9]++(?>[,.][0-9]+)?+/', $ItemPrice->textContent, $rueckgabe)) {
                                $priceEnd = str_replace(',', '', str_replace('.', '', $rueckgabe[0][0]));
                                $priceLength = strlen($priceEnd);
                                $priceEnd = substr($priceEnd, 0, ($priceLength - 2)) . '.' . substr($priceEnd, ($priceLength - 2), 2);
                                $_asin[$k]['price_end'][$seller_i] = (float)$priceEnd;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                                $shippingPrice = $dom->query('span.ShippingPrice');
                                foreach($shippingPrice as $ShippingPrice)
                                {
                                    preg_match_all('/[0-9]{1,}([\,\. ]?[0-9])*/', $ShippingPrice->textContent, $rueckgabe);
                                    if (isset($rueckgabe[0][0])) {
                                        // ...
                                    }
                                }
                                $_asin[$k]['price_total_end'][$seller_i] = $_asin[$k]['price_end'][$seller_i] + $_asin[$k]['shipping_end'][$seller_i];

                                $conditionTag = $dom->query('.Condition');

                                foreach($conditionTag as $ConditionTag)
                                {
                                    $_asin[$k]['main_con'][$seller_i]= 0;
                                    $_asin[$k]['sub_con'][$seller_i] = 0;
                                    $conditionValue = explode(' - ', $ConditionTag->textContent);
                                    if(isset($conditionValue[0])){
                                        // ...
                                    }
                                    if(isset($conditionValue[1])) {
                                        // ...
                                    }
                                }

                                $ratingItem = $dom->query('.Rating');
                                $_asin[$k]['bewertung_end'][$seller_i] = -1;
                                $_asin[$k]['stars_end'][$seller_i] = -1;
                                foreach($ratingItem as $RatingItem)
                                {
                                    echo $RatingItem->textContent; // 99% positiv ... 12 Monaten ... 11.719 Bewertungen ...
                                    // I want to get 99 (which is stars ) and 11719 (which is bewertungen )
                                    preg_match_all('/[0-9]{1,}([\,\. ]?[0-9])*/', preg_replace('/,/', '.', $RatingItem->textContent), $rueckgabe);
                                    if (isset($rueckgabe[0]) AND count($rueckgabe[0]) > 0) {
                                        $_asin[$k]['bewertung_end'][$seller_i] = (int)str_replace('.', '', $rueckgabe[0][count($rueckgabe[0]) - 1]);
                                        $_asin[$k]['stars_end'][$seller_i] = $rueckgabe[0][0];
                                    }
                                }

                                $sellerType = $dom->query('.Name img');
                                $_asin[$k]['merchant_end'][$seller_i] = "N/A";
                                $_asin[$k]['name_end'][$seller_i] = "N/A";
                                $_asin[$k]['img_end'][$seller_i] = "N/A";
                                $_asin[$k]['konk_type'][$seller_i] = 'ERROR';
                                if(count($sellerType) == 1)
                                {
                                    foreach($sellerType as $SellerType)
                                    {
                                        $imgAltText = $SellerType->getAttribute('alt');
                                        $a = explode('.', $imgAltText);
                                        // ...
                                    }
                                }
                                elseif(count($sellerType) == 0)
                                {
                                    $_asin[$k]['img_end'][$seller_i] = 'NO_IMG';
                                    $_asin[$k]['konk_type'][$seller_i] = 'WO_IMG';

                                    $sellerName = $dom->query('.Name b');
                                    foreach($sellerName as $SellerName)
                                    {
                                        $_asin[$k]['name_end'][$seller_i] = $SellerName->textContent;
                                    }

                                    $sellerMerchant = $dom->query('.Name a');
                                    foreach($sellerMerchant as $SellerMerchant)
                                    {
                                        $_asin[$k]['merchant_end'][$seller_i] = str_replace('=', '', substr($SellerMerchant->getAttribute('href'), -14));
                                    }
                                }

                                unset($rueckgabe);
                            }
                            $seller_i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // remove the handle from the multi handle
                curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $handles[$k]);
            }
            // Update Price ...

            // Update Shipping ... 

            // Update Conc ...

            unset($_asin);
            // close the multi curl handle to free system resources
            curl_multi_close($mh);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $error = new Repricing_Dbservices_Error();
        $error->setError($id, $e->getMessage(), $e->getLine(), $e->getFile());
    }
```

And also the script for the price update ( the other update-statements looks similiar)

```
$this->db->beginTransaction();
        try {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($asin); $i++) {
                if (isset($asin[$i]['price_total_end'])) {
                    if (count($asin[$i]['price_total_end']) > 1) {
                        if ($asin[$i]['price_total_end'][0] > 0) {
                            $this->db->query("UPDATE u... SET lowest_price = ? , last_lowest_price_update = ? WHERE id = ?", array(
                                    $asin[$i]['price_total_end'][1],
                                    date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()),
                                    $asin[$i]['pId']
                                ));
                        }
                    } elseif (count($asin[$i]['price_total_end']) == 1) {
                        if ($asin[$i]['price_total_end'][0] >= 0) {
                            $this->db->query("UPDATE u... SET lowest_price = ? , last_lowest_price_update = ? WHERE id = ?", array(
                                -1,
                                date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()),
                                $asin[$i]['pId']
                            ));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $this->db->commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->db->rollBack();
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        $this->db->closeConnection();
```

Do we have an big performance leak in our script, should we go along with an other language, or any other techniques? Every suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all these kind of lines:

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{1,}([\,\. ]?[0-9])*/', $ItemPrice->textContent, $rueckgabe);
if (isset($rueckgabe[0])) {
    // ...
}
```

by:

```
if (preg_match('/([0-9]++)(?>[.,]([0-9]++))?+/', $ItemPrice->textContent, $rueckgabe)) {
    unset($rueckgabe[0]);
    $priceEnd = sprintf("%01.2f", implode('.', $rueckgabe));
    $_asin[$k]['price_end'][$seller_i] = $priceEnd;
}
```

You should replace all your for loops with foreach (then you avoid the `count` on each loop as RaymondN notices it). Example:

Instead of:

```
for ($k = 0; $k < count($handles); $k++) {
```

you write:

```
foreach($handles as $k=>$handle) {
  // you can replace $handles[$k] by $handle
```

It is not very useful to convert the current datetime and format it in "Y-m-d H:i:s" since you can do directly the same with the mySQL statement `NOW()`.

Comment: @minitech: `++` is like `+` but without the backtrack recording (the regex engine is not allowed to backtrack, it is all or nothing)

Comment: Thanks so far. I made some quick try, but my tests showed that your new `preg_match` statement is not working as the old one.  
What i wanted to achieve was, to get a number like this "5,00" or this "5.00". But the new RegEx hands me back `float(0.5)`.

Comment: To show you some excats extraction i updated the `foreach($itemPrice` as it looks now.

Comment: @MichaelHirn: ok, If I understand well, you want to transform any number to a decimal with 2 digits?

Comment: Right i want to extract the number and convert it ( beacuase of the different country styles ) in an decimal with to digits. Standard currency style.

Comment: I changed my code now and took care of these three suggestions. But before i want to restart the `workers`, i would like it if the `foreach($ratingItem as $RatingItem)` loop is running fine. I updated it, how it looks in the old code and what it should do. Your RegEX is working great on price and shipping but on this manner it isn't. Could you maybe take a look at this one, too? I was not able to work this out in your style, which seems to me way more professional.

Answer (score 0):

Don´t use count functions in the for loops that would save some CPU cycles ..

but use.

```
$m = count($array) - 1;
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $m ; $i++) {}
```

Whats the PHP version a new PHP version could possible perform much better.

Answer (score 0):

The most notable thing here is that you are sharding the data too much - when your load average is higher than the number of CPUs, then the OS will start pre-emppting jobs instead of waiting for them to yeild the CPU. As a result overall throughput drops significantly. You seem to have a single CPU - for a cpu bound system like this running on a single core, I'd try 2, 4, 8 and 16 processes to see which gives the optimal behaviour (assuming you need to make the code fit the hardware rather than the other way around).

Your next problem is that the zend framework is very cpu and memory hungry: [Zend is 4 times](http://talks.php.net/show/drupal08/29) slower than [unadorned PHP](http://talks.php.net/show/drupal08/24).

You've got a lot of inlined code in the loops here - while inlining does help performance it makes it a lot more difficult to get useful data out of a profiler - hence my next step after making the Zend-free and reducing the concurrency would be to structure the code into functions and profile it.

Comment: How can you tell that the data is sharded too much? Also, why 2, 4, 8, or 16 processes instead of 1 or 5 or something?

Comment: `load average: 72.96, 72.51, 71.82`. And there's not much point running a single process since at least part of the time (25% of the time from your stats) it will be blocked waiting for curl or local IO